# How to start a fragment into the viewpager from Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an activity and a ViewPager with two fragments. I want to start the fragments through the activity. How can I do it?

Comment: Have tried the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide

Answer (score 0):

> Create a **ViewPager** and a **Tab layout** (if you need  a tab)inside your Activity layout

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/green2"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:tabTextColor="#555050" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabLayout" />
```

> Create a ViewpageAdapter

```
    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String[] names = new String[2];
    List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        names[0] = "Fragment One";
        names[1] = "Fragment Two";
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        return fragmentList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return fragmentTitles.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragment, String title) {

        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitles.add(title);
    }
}
```

> In your **activity class** inside onCreate() 
>      *initialize this view pager*

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
     //adding fragments to page
                viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Fragment1Class(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab1Name));
                viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Fragment2Class(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab2Name));

                //setUp
                viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
                tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

> If you are using tabs, add these too.

```
            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                selectedTabPosition = getTabSelected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                selectedTabPosition = getTabSelected();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                selectedTabPosition = getTabSelected();
            }
        });
```

> **Don't forget to add an empty constructor inside the fragment class**

---

> **To start a specific fragment inside the activity**

Put this inside your activity which starts the activity with fragments

```
    int fragOne=1;
int fragTwo=2;

Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);

//sending data to MainActivity
Bundle extras=new Bundle();
extras.putInt("fragmentId",fragOne);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Inside your activity with fragments**

```
//getting data
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle!=null) {
 int fragId=bundle.getInt("fragmentId");
}
if (fragmentId==1) {
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new fragment1Class(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab1Name));
}else if (fragmentId==2) {
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new fragment2Class(), getResources().getString(R.string.tab1Name));

}
```

Comment: No, I want to start the activity that exists a viewpager with two fragments in it. So I want to start the activity and move to the specific fragment.

Comment: you mean you want to start a specific fragment in the activity when it is created?

Comment: yeah start a specific fragment that is into a viewpager in MainActivity for example and I want to start fragment of another activity (SecoundActivity)

Comment: check the updated answer.I have added at the end of the answer